# Mesh not following Armature

Tags: animation, mesh, armature

I created a basic human model, then copied the vertices and used a shrinkwrap modifier to make spandex-type clothing. I then connected the clothes to the body using Boolean union modifier.

[image]

However, when I try to pose the body using armature, the clothing falls away from the body, even though they are joined. I've tried parenting the clothes to the body as well, with the same results.

[image]

Model File: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you choose boolean instead of a simple join (select your different objects and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>)?

I guess you have several solutions:

- The easiest would be to remove the body mesh under the cloth, or, if you want to keep it, make it invisible with the *Mask* modifier: Select the part of your mesh that you want to hide and assign it a vertex group, give your object the *Mask* modifier, in the *Vertex Group* dropdown menu of the modifier, choose the vertex group you've just created, and, on the right of this dropdown menu click on the inverse arrow.

If you want to keep the body you can try the *Mesh Deform* modifier as explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6s9H8xX7YA) by Daniel Kreuter:

- Parent your body with its clothes to your armature (if the clothes are another object, choose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Armature Deform*).
- Delete all vertex groups from the clothes (select the vertices and on the right of the vertex groups list, down arrow menu and *Remove From All Groups*). Assign these vertices to a new vertex group.
- Create a mesh that is fully closed and that will encompass your whole clothes, i.e. that will be your « cage ».
- Select your cage, then shift select the armature and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *With Automatic Weight*. Give the necessary corrections in *Weight Paint* mode.
- Give your body a *Mesh Deform* modifier (put this modifier above any *Subsurf* modifier) and in the modifier choose the clothes vertex group. Choose the cage as the *Object* and click on *Bind*.