# Can I make clothes be weight-painted and have it have a cloth-simulation?

Tags: weight-painting, cloth-simulation

I have a character with a skirt. I want their skirt simulated, as well attached to the body with weight painted. How will I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several solutions to animate a skirt: [This one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120954/mesh-not-following-armature) that uses ***Mesh Deform*** modifier. Or you can try with the ***Wiggle Bones*** addon. But if you want to use physics, use ***Cloth***:

- Create your skirt, it needs to be another object that the body, parent it to the first spine bone, subdivide it a bit, weight paint the top edge in order to create the pin group:

[image]

- Give it a *Physics > Cloth* simulation, in *Shape > Pin Group*, choose the group you've created:

[image]

- In the modifiers stack, put a *Subdivision Surface* modifier under the *Cloth* modifier. Select the body and give it a *Physics > Collision*. Move, the armature, it should work:

[image]