# Cloth Deforms When I Move Character

Tags: mesh, cloth-simulation

When I attempt to move the rig of the character the clothes overlap for some reason. How can I fix this? I've increased quality steps, applied scale and changed soft body and cloth settings. Would I need to sculpt the cloth?[image]

Comment: I have weight painted and had some progress but the deformation is still slightly there? Am I along the right lines or are there other steps?

Comment: have you watched this tuto? It may give you some answers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg  or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi, yes that was the first tutorial I watched. I have shared the file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Mp88W1gp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a cloth expert but as I told you I think [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbyfuW5Aocg) by Aneesh Arts gives a series of good tricks.

The first thing I would say is that your gown and pants are rather high-poly and it doesn't help to easily work, you should do a low-poly version and give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.

That said I was able to quickly improve your problem with these 2 solutions:

- First, move a bit the vertices of the bottom of the gown with the *Proportional Editing* enabled. You can even create a new shapekey so that the topology only moves when necessary:

[image]

- Find and display the deforming bones in the armature layers:

[image]

- Select the armature, then shift shelect the pants, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, check each bone and use *Blend > Mix* or *Subtract* to increase or decrease their influence. Then do the same for the gown, until there is no clothes overlapping:

[image]

- At the end you should be able to have a good result:

[image]

There is another method that may help, it is to give your clothes a *Mesh Deform* modifier as I explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120954/mesh-not-following-armature), you could try to associate it with cloth simulation...

Comment: Yes that makes a big difference. Thank you! How could I make the clothes low poly?

Comment: You need to retopologize it, i.e. create a second mesh and stick to the original one with the snapping option, look at the leg mesh for example, it's much simpler, you could even have less faces