# Weird rigged object deform

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting, vertex-weights

[image: All good in Rest.]

[image: Bad Automatic Weights clearly visible.]

First of all, I am aware of the issue here, which is that the Automatic Weights couldn't really figure out how to handle the object, that has separate meshes (shoelaces and its rings).

**My question:**

Is there a quick and easy solution for this, or I am doomed to paint it by hand?

My problem with hand painting is that I'm the **wrong** kind of precise, who either makes it full red or full blue, which isn't really good, yet it takes ages. That's why I'm looking for a 2-click, automatic solution or something like that.

I tried Boolean Union to merge them into one mesh, but let's just say I wasn't satisfied with the results and it looked even worse in pose mode.

**Possible solution, that I don't know how to do:**

Is it possible to have the boots follow a simple dummy mesh, that is parented to the armature instead of the boots?

Comment: You should be able to fix that in Weight Paint mode, but as you suggest with your "dummy mesh" you could use a trick like Mesh Deform modifier, as I explain here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120954/mesh-not-following-armature

Comment: The dummy method worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I would make a quick (manifold) cage for the model, autoweight that, and then data transfer weights onto my boots.