# Weight painted scalf not moving as expected

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

Good morning!

I'm having some issues with a character im creating (sorry for the bad topology and so, it's the first one). It has kind of a scalf around his torso.
After weight painting it, it clips into his torso when moving a spine bone.

[image]

I've weight painted this way (the whole scalf painted in weight 1 with the spine bone)and also separated for every bone, but it does the same. I tried to merge it with the rest of the mesh (it's the same object but not merged) but at least til I saw, it didn't work.

[image]

I wanted to know if you guys had any advice for a newbie like me. Thanks in advance, I will provide de Blender file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uJz2W66lmq4ujqmwnWG2JYTkJjKRzcyQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please upload and embed the images to the Blender StackExchange site? This way they will not get lost and we don't have to click on each and then click return and so on.

Comment: @Blunder Yes, it's fixed! Sorry, didnt know how to do it the first time

Answer (score 0):

Each spine bone influences the whole strap (for example the top spine as seen in the picture below), it should not be the case, you need to remove the bottom part of this vertex group with the brush *Subtract* mode.

[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks for your fast comment!
I tried what you told me to, but the thing it still clips through the mesh when bending it. 
https://imgur.com/O43URnF
https://imgur.com/GJlN7pE

Comment: I think you need to work it in detail, add or remove edge loops, add and remove weight paint, give it thickness, if it still doesn't work maybe try a Mesh Deform modifier as explained here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120954/mesh-not-following-armature