# Layers of clothing for character models?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation, collision

I've been messing around with the sewing tool recently and I'm wondering how you add more layers of clothing over each other (specifically on character models). The cloth simulation doesn't seem to be handling multiple layers of cloth colliding with each other very well. Tweaking cloth/collision settings for hours and nothing is giving me good results.

Comment: you could delete or hide (with a Mask modifier) the layers of cloth underneath to avoid the overlapping?

Comment: that could work! But what if the cloth is moving around? it wont stay positioned over the underlying geometry the whole time, wouldnt the mask would have to be moving with the clothes?

Comment: you can also use a Mesh Deform cage to deform several meshes, see the method here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6s9H8xX7YA

Comment: and see my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120954/mesh-not-following-armature